# OSGI: getting property information from DS

Tags: java, osgi, declarative-services

I have the following declarative service:

```
@Component(
    immediate = false,
    property={"propA=valueA","propB=valueB","propC=valueC"},
    scope=ServiceScope.SINGLETON
)
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceI{...}
```

And this the code I do to find this service(manually) by propA:

```
String filter = "(&(objectClass=" + ServiceI.class.getName() + ")(propA=valueA))";
ServiceReference[] serviceReferences = bundleContext.getServiceReferences((String)null,filter);
ServiceI service=(ServiceI) bundleContext.getService(serviceReferences[0]);
```

How can I get valueB of propB and valueC of propC of found service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getProperty` of a `ServiceReference` instance :

```
Object propBValue = serviceReference.getProperty("propB");
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly out of scope. With annotations the code would look like:

```
 @Reference(target="(propA=valueA)")
 void setI(ServiceI s, Map<String,Object> properties) {
    String propB = properties.get("propB");
    String propC = properties.get("propC");
    ...
 }
```